# Error message when trying to install sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, dropbox

I am a bit of a newbie at this but have been running Kubuntu from ubuntu 14.04 which runs fine, I have been trying to get the dropbox icon to appear in the sys tray (it runs in the background ok) but have hit a wall.

I get the following dialogue from the terminal:

```
W: GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E
```

the public key is not available?

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox’s repository key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E
```

Dropbox’s repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
```

Update and Install

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install
```

Run dropbox

```
nautilus-dropbox
```

Follow instructions....

Comment: No problem remember to close the question by clicking the ChecK MarK

Answer (score 2):

**2022 answer**

Apt-key is deprecated.

```
curl -sL "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xFC918B335044912E" | gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/dropbox.gpg --import && chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
```

Comment: Thanks - been searching for about an hour for this correct 2022 Dropbox Apt-Key answer.